# CPLEX debug window freezes

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to code my math model in CPLEX language using C++ (Concert Technology). when I run my code in the compiler window read my inputs and freezes. when trying to debug my code, the visual studio shows the following line as a breakpoint.

```
//constraint 2
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++) {
    IloExpr Constraint2(env);
    for (rr = 0; rr < AvailableRooms; rr++) {
        Constraint2 += RoomCapacity[rr] * Y[cc][rr];
        mod.add(Constraint2 >= Students[cc]); // this line
        Constraint2.end();
    }
}
```

i have set up the parameters and variables as follow:

```
double RoomCapacity[AvailableRooms];
double Students[NumberOfCourses];

//Ycr
IloBoolVarArray2 Y(env, NumberOfCourses);
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++)
    Y[cc] = IloBoolVarArray(env, AvailableRooms);
```

I do not understand what is wrong with my constraint!

Comment: Could you possibly print `rr` and `cc` values after each iteration? Or it happens during the first iteration?

Comment: i think it does not go through the iteration

Comment: Could you include the stack trace when it freezes? And by the way, you got this CPLEX library in debug?

Comment: I think I am not that professional with the terminologies. What do you mean by stack trace? 

I do not understand your second question.  I made a cplex environment at the beginning of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong: In the very first inner iteration you add `Constraint2` to your model and then you `end()` that variable. So in the second inner iteration, you are doing `Constraint2 += ...` while the `Constraint2` object was already deleted. This will lead to undefined behavior (hang, crash, ...).

I guess what you wanted to write is this (pull `add()` and `end()` out of the inner loop):

```
   for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++) {
      IloExpr Constraint2(env);
      for (rr = 0; rr < AvailableRooms; rr++) {
         Constraint2 += RoomCapacity[rr] * Y[cc][rr];
      }
      mod.add(Constraint2 >= Students[cc]);
      Constraint2.end();
   }
```